# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser starts at item number 2 instead of number 1

Tags: php, dom, find, html-parsing, steam-web-api

i'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser to receive certain info that i require, but it seems like the parser outputs the 1st. item it finds. I'm using this code:

`$html = file_get_html("http://steamcommunity.com/id/" . $username . "/wishlist/");

foreach($html->find('.wishlistRow') as $e)

{

$item = $e->outertext;

}

echo $item;`

this outputs the 2nd item on the wishlist, but not the first. This also applies to other projects i'm working on, and i would really appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` is out of the `foreach`, so it will only output the last item.
Move it inside `foreach`.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe i missed that. Thank you!